# Incoming SMS contents

Tags: java, android, sms, converters, android-broadcastreceiver

I wish I could get the contents of an incoming sms but its not working .. 
In fact, no toast will appear, and nothing appears in the log, I think the myreceiver is not initialized ...
So here is the manifest, the onCreate the first activity, and my receiver java file : Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.locateit.antholife.locateit">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/locate"
    android:label="@string/app_nameprincipal"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Changelog"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_changelog"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBfmF3WWxsPhufZR5keiDNRy-33hJI1rvM" />

    <activity
        android:name=".lequipe"
        android:label="@string/nomequipe" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Setting"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_setting" />
    <activity android:name=".MDPinterne" />
    <activity android:name=".Bluetooth"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

onCreate :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    MyReceiver sms = new MyReceiver();
    Log.v("aha3", "smslancer");
```

and java file :

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public MyReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
    if (extra != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extra.get("pdus");
        final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        }
        if (messages.length > -1) {
            Log.v("Ch", "Marche1");
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                Log.v("Ch", "Marche2");
                final String messageBody = messages[i].getMessageBody();
                final String phoneNumber = messages[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Expéditeur:" + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Message : " + messageBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Move your receiver XML in your manifest to within the application tags.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/locate"
android:label="@string/app_nameprincipal"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

.......
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true" >
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: yes I understood, I answered too quickly, I try its :) thank you